# Laravel Cashier Subscription v10.5

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am trying to implement a subscription with Cashier. I am not using the user table but a customer table which I have defined OK in .env with

```
CASHIER_MODEL=App\Customer
```

The appropriate other fields are added to the customer table.

I first wish to get some information on the customer so they fill in a simple form which includes their name, email, country and a password. I then save the customer->id as a session variable.

I have a table of plans which contains the stripe subscription reference and the test reference. I have set these up in Stripe.

After recording the customer details I take them to a view which is where they input their card details. The customer is found on this page as the id is passed to the view and also set a session variable.

```
$fs = App\Customer::find($id);
$pl = App\Plan::find(3);
$amount = $pl->cost * 100;
session(['subscriber' => $id]);
```

Plan id 3 is my test plan but will be replaces when I get things to work and so my form is

```
<form action="/subscriptionPayment" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <script
          src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}"
          data-amount="{{ $amount }}"
          data-name="{{ $pl->name }}"
          data-email="{{ $fs->email }}"
          data-currency="gbp">
        </script>
</form>
```

This does record the stripeID in the table but not the last 4 numbers of the card or the card brand. (I am using 4242 4242 4242 4242).

The controller method is

```
public function subscriptionPayment(Request $request)
  {

    $pl = Plan::find(3);
    $amount = $pl->cost *100;
    $cu = Cust::find( session('customer') );

    $paymentMethods = $cu->paymentMethods();
    $intent = $cu->createSetupIntent();

    $stripeToken = $cu->stripe_id;
    $cu->newSubscription($pl->name, $pl->test_stripe_plan)->create($stripeToken);     //test strip id
    return 'Charge successful, you get the course!';

    }

}
```

I did dd the $intent which returned

```
Stripe\SetupIntent {#500 ▼
  +saveWithParent: false
  #_opts: Stripe\Util\RequestOptions {#503 ▶}
  #_originalValues: array:20 [▶]
  #_values: array:20 [▶]
  #_unsavedValues: Stripe\Util\Set {#490 ▶}
  #_transientValues: Stripe\Util\Set {#506 ▶}
  #_retrieveOptions: []
  #_lastResponse: Stripe\ApiResponse {#502 ▶}
  id: "seti_1FyFFyF7aDMrgjaujaPqH939"
  object: "setup_intent"
  application: null
  cancellation_reason: null
  client_secret: "seti_1FyFFyF7aDMrgjaujaPqH939_secret_GVFlyidVC9hiJVM3FDrXMoyxO0etcPL"
  created: 1578392750
  customer: null
  description: null
  last_setup_error: null
  livemode: false
  mandate: null
  metadata: Stripe\StripeObject {#512 ▶}
  next_action: null
  on_behalf_of: null
  payment_method: null
  payment_method_options: Stripe\StripeObject {#508 ▶}
  payment_method_types: array:1 [▶]
  single_use_mandate: null
  status: "requires_payment_method"
  usage: "off_session"
}
```

The subscription fails with

```
No such PaymentMethod: cus_GVEuKhg2BUE7BB
```

This is the correct customer number as recorded in the database.

Help greatly appreciated indeed.

Comment: `$stripeToken = $cu->stripe_id;` — that's not right, the token is the value you get form Checkout, it should be in $request somewhere as the stripeToken POST parameter; not the customer ID which you're . getting currently.

Comment: I did a dd on the incoming request and got

    "stripeToken" => "tok_1FyGbRF7aDMrgjauoF69KPak"
    "stripeTokenType" => "card"


So I amended my code to 
````
$stripeToken = $request->stripeToken;
paymentMethods = $cu->paymentMethods();
    $intent = $cu->createSetupIntent();

    $cu->newSubscription($pl->name, $pl->test_stripe_plan)->create($stripeToken); 
````

and now I am getting:

````
No such PaymentMethod: tok_1FyGbRF7aDMrgjauoF69KPak
````

Comment: I don't think you can really use SetupIntents with tokens. You're using legacy Checkout here too which doesn't really work with new things like SetupIntents(you should be using an Elements PaymentMethod integration, or new Checkout). You can make this work by creating a PaymentMethod from the token at least, and using that ID. I don't know how you do in Lavarel but it's https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-card (create a PaymentMethod and pass `card.token = tok_xxx`